# OSX : Prevent NSWindow from interacting parentwindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

In app, launching another `NSWindowController` using `showWindow` method, from my `main WindowController`.

So there is base `WindowController1` from where on button `click` I am opening another `WindowController2` using `showWindow` method.

Now I wants to prevent user-interaction with `WindowController1` until `WindowController2` is open and wants to keep on focus to `WindowController2` until user close is by clicking "Close" icon?

I have search few things on Stackoverflow and Google but did not found helpful thing any idea on this?

Thanks

Comment: Make WindowController2 a sheet?

Comment: thats good option, but I want to open different window.

Comment: Use `NSApplication`s `runModalForWindow:`.

Comment: @Willeke when I use runModel, double click on NSTokenField suggestion is not working. Is there any way to achieve the same behaviour with some other approach?

Comment: @prabhu Post a new question please.